# Angular UI elements: do I still need jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I'm just starting out in Angular, and I get the MVC model for organizing data architecturally, but I'm not sure about building custom UI elements without using jQuery (or vanilla js).

For example, I want to build a custom slider, sort of like a progress bar that a user can click (or touch) and drag to change the value. Is angular built for that, or would it require a hack-y solution? Would it be some combination of mouseover, mousedown, mousemove, mouseup events?

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider)?

Comment: If I can get that working with touch, yes. But thanks, that's a great starting point.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS has its own lite version of jQuery. The document is here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

It is not supposed to handle heavy DOM manipulation and it will not support such thing in the future. If you want to build a custom slider, there is a plug-in called angular-ui: http://angular-ui.github.io/

However, Angular-ui uses jQuery as well. I also notice they don't have a built-in slider component, so my suggestion is that first you should use angular.element, if this cannot satisfy whatever you need, use jQuery.

Comment: Angular UI doesn't strictly require jQuery. Some of its directives do, but not all of them.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'm trying to build in touch functionality on a phonegap app, and there's a lot of stuff saying jQuery mobile is too bloated to be fast and effective so I was looking for an alternative. Looks like I'm back on the market for a good mobile UI framework.

Comment: Try Zepto.js. It's very mobile friendly and extremely small. It covers a lot of core jQuery functions while being only 9.7k in size. http://zeptojs.com/

Comment: Sencha Touch is the best i've found. The docs are weak but it's a very clean powerful framework. http://www.sencha.com/products/touch